# Swift convert bool to NSRange

Tags: swift, casting

This does not work (of course) nothing prints and Xcode spits out an warning about Cast always failing:

```
let bool = true  
if let range = bool as? NSRange {
  print(range)
}
```

Why does this work?  I would think it should not:

```
let bool: AnyObject = true    
if let range = bool as? NSRange {
  print(range)
}
```

This will actually print out `(0,0)` ... which might kind of make sense if it were `false`, but it's `true` so, yeah... doesn't make sense to me.

Same behavior in Swift 1.2 or 2.0.  But it's kind of making me doubt Swift's type system a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much a fault of Swift's type system as it is a side effect of the Objective-C interoperability.

`let bool: AnyObject = true` is effectively `let bool = NSNumber(bool: true)`. This is no longer a Swift Bool, but it's an Obj-C (Foundation) NSNumber object.

Then, `let range = bool as? NSRange` tries to convert your value to NSRange. NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue, so this is similar to

```
let range = NSNumber(bool: true).rangeValue
```

which returns {0,0}. That's how NSValue works. Here's some disassembly from Hopper:

[image: disassembly]

This might be fixable from the Swift team's perspective, if they're more careful about checking the type before doing the conversion. You should consider [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: That makes complete sense, although it also breaks an assumption I had about the `as?` operator, namely that it only checks for a certain Types and nothing more.  I did not realize that it would also coerce values.  So far as I can tell, though, this only occurs with `AnyObject`... I'm not sure if I should file a bug on this.  Seems like it's intended behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the original value type?  Seems like the type information is lost when it's converted to `NSNumber`. Might need to post another SO question on that...

Comment: You can use `objCType` to get some idea, but it won't be perfect (NSNumber doesn't always store the exact type). You could also consider `as? NSNumber` to do a class check without coercion. But I would recommend simply avoiding mixing NSRange with NSNumbers. Do you really need to use AnyObject here?

Comment: It might seem like confusing behavior, but I'd say that "`let bool: AnyObject = true`" doesn't really make sense in the first place, unless you're really trying to deal with NSArray/NSDictionary.

Comment: The code I provided was an arbitrary example I'm not using in production.  The production code is a translation layer used to convert items for use in a `NSPredicate` that's applied against a back-end db.  I check for specific types that need to be converted into a db-safe types.  In this case, `NSRange` is stored as a string, so I check for that type.  Got a crash when a `Bool` was passed in and it was converted into a `String` because it was coerced into `NSRange`.  Easy to fix, but yeah, can't get away from `AnyObject`...

Comment: Sure. I just feel that "`as? NSRange`" is weird; there's no equivalent in Obj-C (NSRange isn't a class). If you're dealing with NSNumber vs. NSString, you can check for NSNumber. But there's no unique class wrapper for NSRange unless you make your own.

Comment: That's true and if I thought about it a little more I'd have realized my mistake.  I was thinking that `as?` was more a type checker than a kind of `isKindOfClass`.  In another part of the app, it seems natural to ask the Persistence Layer "get object where Range == x", passing in `NSRange`.  I failed to consider that `AnyObject` would convert the type into an object...  I guess it's obvious when you look at the type signature, but when you're typing away... meh, I missed it.  Swift gets you in the habit of thinking about Types, and less about classes.